# CakePHP: Bin cake bake table doesn't exist

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a table `DeletedTransactions` using migrations.

```
bin\cake bake migration CreateDeletedTransactions deleted_id:integer customer_id:integer description:text amount:decimal transaction_type_id:integer deleted_by:integer deleted_date:date
```

I can see that it is created successfully in my db and is listed when I run the command `bin\cake bake model`.

But when I try to build the model with `bin\cake bake model DeletedTransactions` then I get this error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.knowledgebasearticles' doesn't exist.....

This is the structure of `knowledgebase_articles`:

```
CREATE TABLE knowledgebase_articles (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  content text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  kbcategory_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  created_date date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

But it is for another table in the db (which by the way does exist....)

Stack Trace:

[image]

The KnowledgebaseArticlesTable initialize()

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('knowledgebaseArticles');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('UsersBy', [
            'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
            'className' => 'Users'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('KnowledgebaseArticlesCategories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'kbcategory_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags', [
            'foreignKey' => 'knowledgebase_article_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'joinTable' => 'knowledgebase_articles_tags'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that you used for this?

Comment: @creyD ok I edited my question with the migration code

Comment: bake script looking for related tables: DeletedTable (deleted_id), CustomersTable (customer_id), TransactionTypes (transaction_type_id)

Comment: @Salines but I get the error for a table that is not related at all... KnowledgeBaseArticles which is not related to transactions.

Comment: @netdev we don't see in your question.

Comment: @Salines ok I updated the question with the structure of knowledgebase_articles table

Comment: @netdev .  kbcategory_id . -> KbcategoriesTable

Comment: @Salines but why it checks for associations in a totally different table? knowledgebase_articles has nothing to do with deleted_transactions table. And kbcategoriesTable does exist....

Comment: For starters, check the corresponding stacktrace to figure how / from where this is actually triggered.

Comment: @ndm I posted the stack trace because I can't figure it myself...

Comment: try to clear all cache ```bin/cake cake cache clearAll``` then bake your model

Comment: @Salines cleared it but I get the same error

Comment: Are you sure the cache was cleared? Have you checked the `tmp` folder? According to the stacktrace, CakePHP is looking for that table because a table object reports that its table name is something that starts with `knowledgebaseAr` (probably `knowledgebaseArticles`). Do you have a `KnowledgebaseArticles` table class? If so, what does its `initialize()` method code look like?

Comment: Yes I did cleared the cache. I updated the question with initialize() method of knowledgebaseArticlesTable

Comment: And there it is `$this->setTable('knowledgebaseArticles');`... the table name should be `knowledgebase_articles`.

Comment: @ndm That was it indeed! but please help me... why it looks for the knowledgebase_articles table when I am trying to bake model for another table? there is no association between the table that I am trying to bake its model and the problematic one...

Comment: Bake needs to check the schema of all tables in order to be able to resolve possible `hasOne`, `hasMany`, and `belongsToMany` associations, because for those associations, the foreign key columns from which that information can be inferred, would reside in the other (associated) table, not in the one for which the model is currently being baked (for example `article_id` in `comments` table would resolve to `Articles hasMany Comments`).